# Lose POST Data in Codeigniter 3.0.4 when I use bootstrap Validator

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I apologize in advance if I am missing something here.
I have a simple TEST controller and view. The form works perfectly if I DON'T use this script.

I am NOT using AJAX or CSRF protection.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.vform').bootstrapValidator();
        });
    </script>
```

If I use the above script I lose POST data.

This is my simple TEST view

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="<?=$description?>">
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?=$keywords?>">
        <meta name="author" content="xyz">
        <title><?=$title;?></title>
        <link href="<?=$canonical?>" rel="canonical">

        <link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<?=base_url();?>assets/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?=base_url()?>favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="<?=base_url()?>favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/shiv/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/respond/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <header class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="well col-xs-12 col-sm-9 center-block">
                    <?php
                        $att = array(
                            'class' => 'form-horizontal vform',
                            'name' => 'admin_login_form',
                            'id' => 'admin_login_form',
                        );
                        echo form_open(base_url().'test/login', $att);
                            echo form_fieldset('Admin Login');
                    ?>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="100" data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="Please enter your email" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="emailmsg">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="50" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="passwordmsg">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                            <input type="submit" name="login_sub" id="login_sub" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="loginmsg">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                            echo form_fieldset_close();
                        echo form_close();
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <p>&copy;Test</p>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Validator -->
        <script src="<?=base_url();?>assets/js/bsvalid/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.vform').bootstrapValidator();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my simple test controller

```
    <?php
        class Test extends CI_Controller {

            public function login () {
                $this->load->helper('url');
                $data = array();
                $data['description'] = 'Admin page - Test';
                $data['keywords'] = 'Test, admin, login';
                $data['title'] = 'Test - Admin - Login';
                $data['canonical'] = 'test/one';

                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                //Form validation rules
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[50]|valid_email');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]');

                //Form Submission
                if ($this->input->post('login_sub')) {
                    echo "jjjj";
                    var_dump($_POST);
                    if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {
                        echo 'All is well';
                    }

                }

                $this->load->view('test/one', $data);
            }
```

I tried using versions 0.4.9 and 0.5.2 of [Bootstrap Validator](https://plugins.jquery.com/bootstrapValidator/). 
I am getting POST output if i remove the validator jquery. But when I include the validator jquery segment, the page just seems to refresh on submit and there is no output.
I am honestly clueless because I am not using any AJAX or CSRF. How could a purely client side jquery function interfere with POST data?
P.S. I have also tried using bootstrap validators jquery function instead of inline data-bv validation rules.
P.P.S. The same code works perfectly on codeigniter 3.0.3 ... I am inclined to think this is a codeigniter 3.0.4 issue.
I would be obliged if someone could guide me.

Comment: There might be an error when you call the JavaScript line, do you get any in the debugger when you refresh the page ?

Comment: @Bubblesphere no error in chrome console ... kept watching the whole time ...

Comment: Instead of this `if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {` why not try `if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I lose the whole POST data even if I remove $this->form_validation part. Tried with == TRUE ... still no post data ...

Comment: Have you set your base url correct? I have added a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if you have set your base_url it is not required but sometimes if your using codeIgniter 3 versions will not submit form correct

Config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_name/';
```

Test Controller

File Name: Test.php **check first letter upper case**.

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function login () {

        $data['description'] = 'Admin page - Test';
        $data['keywords'] = 'Test, admin, login';
        $data['title'] = 'Test - Admin - Login';
        $data['canonical'] = 'test/one';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[50]|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

             $this->load->view('test/one', $data);

        } else {

            var_dump($this->input->post());

            echo 'All is well';

        }

    }

}
```

jQuery place in side head tags works much better. But still leave bootstrap js at bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description ;?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords;?>">
<meta name="author" content="xyz">
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
<link href="<?php echo $canonical;?>" rel="canonical">

<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bsvalid/bootstrapValidator.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js');?>"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$att = array(
    'class' => 'form-horizontal vform',
    'name' => 'admin_login_form',
    'id' => 'admin_login_form',
);

echo form_open('test/login', $att);

?>


// Form Content Here


<?php echo form_close();?>

<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#admin_login_form').bootstrapValidator();
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code works. The issue is that your code does not use if  `($this->input->post('login_sub'))` while i was enclosing `if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE)` the within `if ($this->input->post('login_sub'))` ... What I am wondering is .... why would this cause POST data loss? ... Like i mentioned previously, the code works codeigniter 3.0.3 ... This issue crops up in codeigniter 3.0.4. Also why would a pure jquery function which does NOT use AJAX cause server side POST data loss? Accepting your answer. Thank you so much for spending your valuable time on this.

Comment: Also isn't it the recommended way to keep form processing stuff inside `($this->input->post('login_sub'))`?

Comment: It better to use form validation like in the controller but if you do not want to use form validation then by all means use that.